# How would I go about texturing this?

Tags: mesh, texturing, sculpting

[image]

I finished this sculpt a few weeks ago and just came back to it to finish it up, but I don't know the first thing about realistic texturing. Any recommended tutorials? Apologize, very new to this.

Comment: You can't uv-unwrap a highpoly model. So, the next step after sculpting a highpoly model would be the retopology process, so you actually have a model that can be textured.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that'll be the next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @metaphor_set already said, you cannot UV unwrap this high poly model without having a huge headache. That's why you need to do something called retopology, this is when you wrap a low poly mesh on top of the high poly mesh to get a low poly copy of the high poly mesh. There are many tools and add-ons that will make your life easier.

First I explain how you can do it without add-ons:

1. Add a new object with a single vertex
2. In the modifer tab add the subdivision surface modifier and the shrink wrap modifier
3. Enter edit mode, select the vertex and enable "snap to" (the magnet) and select faces

Now if you extrude the vertex over the object you will see it snaps to the surface of the object. With some tricks you can get very clean and easy to handle and animate topology

But if you want to have it even easier (I recommend) use retopoflow, an addon that basically does all the settings for you and has many tools for easy retopology. Tho I will not go  further here as there are many great tutorials on it already